# How can I calculate square root of a matrix using IDL?

Tags: matrix, idl-programming-language

I am trying to calculate square root of a large dimension matrix using IDL but failed. Any solution or tips would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is it failing?  What have you tried?  You may want to refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get more/better answers to your question (though it seems @mgalloy knows what you're referring to).

Answer (score 2):

Use my routines [mg_alogm](https://github.com/mgalloy/mglib/blob/master/src/matrices/mg_alogm.pro) and [mg_expm](https://github.com/mgalloy/mglib/blob/master/src/matrices/mg_expm.pro) to compute:

```
sqrt_A = mg_expm(0.5 * mg_alogm(A))
```